# Problem on subspace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I was asked the following question in a test.

> If a Vector Space is the set of real valued continuous functions over $\mathbb R$, then find the subspace of:
>   $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 9\frac{dy}{dx} +2y=0$$

I'm a bit confused in the question. I first thought it meant to verify for all functions which satisfy the differential equation, whether they form a subspace.

Then I thought that I should take two functions $y1$ and $y2$ and check whether $y1 + y2$ and $a.y$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ also satisfy the differential equation given that $y1$ and $y2$ satisfy it.

I'm not quite sure whether I interpreted the question correctly or whether I approached it correctly.

Can someone also post how the question should actually be worded?

Comment: This is a really poorly written question (not on your part, obviously). How does one find a subspace of an equation?

Comment: I assumed that I've to verify whether it is a subspace. Is that what it means?

Comment: That would be *my* guess, but who knows what your professor is thinking. The fact of the matter is that there are words missing.

Comment: She substituted "verify whether it is a subspace" almost every time in class with "find the subspace". So it's the most likely interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear differential equation solutions has vector space structure. Checking it for your equation is easy. If you have two solutions $y_1,y_2$, prove $ay_1+b y_2$ is a solution. The order of your equation is the dimension of the vector space so you need to find two independet solutions of

$$
y''(x)-9y'(x)+2y(x)=0
$$

Try to resolve the equation. Solutions you should find are $y_1(x)=\exp(-(\sqrt{73}-9)x/2)$ and $y_2=\exp((\sqrt{73}+9)x/2)$.